# Octopus deployed continuous WebJob not running simultaneously in two locations

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, octopus-deploy, azure-webjobssdk

I have a continuous webjob that needs to run two webapps in two locations on a TimerTrigger.  When I deploy the webjob from Visual Studio to both locations everything works well and both webjobs run at the same time.

Now I'm ready to start deploying this with Octopus-Deploy.  I have successfully created a plan with two steps that does that and puts the assemblies in the correct location under the web apps (`app_data\jobs\continuous\{jobname}`) in Azure.  The problem is that only one webjob executes its job at a time even though both webjobs have a status of Running.  If I stop and start the one that's executing, the other webjob starts executing its job while the one I turned off/on has a status of running, but doesn't ever execute its job.  Also, if I redeploy just one of them from visual studio, they both execute their jobs at both locations again.

I'm not doing anything with Singletons and have actually tried turning it off by using a 'settings.job' file with `{is_singleton: false}`.  Is there something Octopus is doing with the package that makes Azure think the webjob is a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is caused by using the same storage account and host id for both of the apps that you deployed. When you do that, the WebJobs SDK views it as a single Web App that has been scaled out to two instances, and makes sure the timer is only run on one of them.

The simplest solution is to use a different storage account for each app.

Comment: You're right, I created separate storage accounts for each webjob.  Once I changed the connection strings they both executed their jobs as expected.  I do have one follow-up question.  What is the host id?

Comment: @mathewc can explain this better than me, so I'll let him shine in :)

Comment: HostId refers to JobHostConfiguration.HostId (in source [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHostConfiguration.cs#L106)). Basically it is an ID shared by multiple instances of the same JobHost. The runtime makes sure all instances share the same ID. The singleton behavior of TimerTrigger is explained in the wiki [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger).